# Cannot Install FIREBASE via NPM GLOBALLY (Error 127)

Tags: node.js, firebase, npm

I cannot install firebase via `npm install -g firebase`.
I receive the following error that I could not find a solution for:

The issue seem to be relatedd to core-js & protobufjs which cannot be postinstall.

Note: I did reinstall node.js multiple times already - without any luck.

```
51 http fetch POST 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/-/npm/v1/security/advisories/bulk 374ms
52 timing auditReport:getReport Completed in 377ms
53 silly audit report {}
54 timing auditReport:init Completed in 0ms
55 timing reify:audit Completed in 377ms
56 timing reifyNode:node_modules/@firebase/polyfill/node_modules/core-js Completed in 1368ms
57 timing reifyNode:node_modules/core-js Completed in 1470ms
58 timing reify:unpack Completed in 1470ms
59 timing reify:unretire Completed in 0ms
60 timing build:queue Completed in 1ms
61 info run core-js@3.18.1 postinstall node_modules/core-js node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
62 info run core-js@3.6.5 postinstall node_modules/@firebase/polyfill/node_modules/core-js node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
63 info run core-js@3.18.1 postinstall { code: 127, signal: null }
64 info run core-js@3.6.5 postinstall { code: 127, signal: null }
65 timing reify:rollback:createSparse Completed in 338ms
66 timing reify:rollback:retireShallow Completed in 31ms
67 timing command:install Completed in 2501ms
68 verbose stack Error: command failed
68 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs2\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\promise-spawn\index.js:64:27)
68 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:390:28)
68 verbose stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1064:16)
68 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:301:5)
69 verbose pkgid core-js@3.18.1
70 verbose cwd C:\Users\chmit_000
71 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19042
72 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs2\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs2\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "core-js"
73 verbose node v16.10.0
74 verbose npm  v7.24.0
75 error code 127
76 error path C:\Users\chmit_000\node_modules\core-js
77 error command failed
78 error command bash -c node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
79 error /bin/bash: node: command not found
80 verbose exit 127
```

Answer (score 1):

The package meant for global installation is `firebase-tools`. That's the CLI used for deploying your app (or parts of it) to firebase, as well as performing other administrative tasks. The `firebase` package is the library used for accessing firebase backend/cloud functions in a web/mobile project.

If you're looking to install the CLI, run `npm install -g firebase-tools`.

Here are links to both packages:

[firebase](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase)

[firebase-tools](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase-tools)

Comment: Unfortunately the same error occurs:

Comment: This might be a PATH issue. Are you using NVM?

Comment: You were right this was/is a path issue. The issue occurred for the postinstall. The issue was the 'git bash' that I installed quite some time back. Adding git bash to the env variables solved the issue.